# Do I have to sign my ClickOnce manifest?

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, signing

I have a VS2012 solution (WinForm vb.net) which I deploy thanks to ClickOnce. I do some tests today for deploying this application. I'm able to publish and deploy this application **without signing the ClickOnce manifest nor signing the assembly**. On the Signing tab of my project I uncheck 'Sign the ClickOnce manifests' and  'Sign the assembly'. I don't have any errors (about assembly not signed) when installing this application.

I copy the published folder on a USB key and install it on another computer without problem. I'm also able to update my application and install these updates automatically (thanks to ClickOnce).

I read a lot about ClickOnce and signing and it seems I don't have to sign for WinForm application.

Does someone can confirm this? I wonder if I copy my ClickOnce folder on a share on the network company if I can always install it without problems?

Tomorrow I will have the opportunity to try to install on the company's network (not today).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Signing ClickOnce manifests is optional since .Net 3.5. See here for confirmation from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfz60ccf.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. Effectively, I had an old application targetted .Net Framework 2.0 and whatever I do (uncheck signing, ...) it always check it after publishing. Finally, I targetted .Net Framework 3.5 and now I am able to publish without signing my ClickOnce solution.