# Exception reading manifest

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, manifest

i have a strange problem. I recently changed the certificate to SHA256, target framework is .NET 4.0, no other changes, i get the below error when loading my VSTO add-in.

> Name:  From: file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/SomeAddin.vsto
>
> ************** Exception Text ************** System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Exception
>   reading manifest from
>   file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/SomeAddin.vsto: the manifest may
>   not be valid or the file could not be opened. --->
>   System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Manifest XML
>   signature is not valid. --->
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException:
>   SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm
>   supplied.    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignedInfo(AsymmetricAlgorithm
>   key)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignature(AsymmetricAlgorithm
>   key)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignatureReturningKey(AsymmetricAlgorithm&
>   signingKey)    at
>   System.Deployment.Internal.CodeSigning.SignedCmiManifest.Verify(CmiManifestVerifyFlags
>   verifyFlags)    at
>   System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream
>   s)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream
>   s)    at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String
>   localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.GetManifests(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()

strangely, when i remove "file:///" from my manifest URL in the registry it works fine, this is on .NET 4.0.

The issue is also not seen on 4.5 framework, with that "file:///", any thoughts ??

```
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <NoStandardLibraries>false</NoStandardLibraries>
    <RootNamespace>Some.Addin</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Some.Addin</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <ManifestCertificateThumbprint>{somethumbprint}</ManifestCertificateThumbprint>
    <ManifestKeyFile>
    </ManifestKeyFile>
    <SignManifests>true</SignManifests>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>Somefile.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
    <DelaySign>false</DelaySign>
```

This is different from  [“Manifest XML signature is not valid” on client machine but works fine on developer computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573837/manifest-xml-signature-is-not-valid-on-client-machine-but-works-fine-on-develo) because removing "file:///" from the manifest file fixes the problem. If .NET 4.5 was involved, then the problem should have persisted.

Comment: Can you please remove the duplicate tag ? I have updated the question with why its not the same.

Comment: Note the _"or the file could not be opened"_ verse. The URL is probably invalid/unsupported.

Comment: :) the file is there..  Duh..  So brings me to the part that confuses me, why does removing 'file:///'  make it work?  Without the certificate upgradation it worked fine.

Comment: Darn, I didn't read the exception to the end. The root one is "SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied." I'd try to debug this with ILSpy/.NET Reflector. Still maintain that most probably, it's "invalid/unsupported" - maybe some bug/limitation that was fixed in 4.5.

Comment: I am also facing same issue some of the systems working fine, some of the systems not working through in error message From: file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/xxx/yyy/AddWordIn.vsto, any one got solution please explain me