# How to Sign ClickOnce with Sha256 Cert for .NET 4.0 like Visual Studio Update 3

Tags: batch-file, command-line, visual-studio-2013, mage

I am trying to deploy an outlook add-in using a clickonce installer. I have a batch file that almost works, however, I get the error "xml signature is not valid" when trying to install on Windows XP. It is pretty well known that XP fails with SHA256 certificates [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826798/manifest-xml-signature-is-not-valid). It is also known that Update 3 for Visual Studio 2013 fixes the issue when you publish using Visual Studio interface. I am wondering how I can accomplish the same fix using signtool or mage on the command line. Here is my current batch file that works for everything except Windows XP:

```
:: Build and publish
msbuild /target:clean,publish /property:MapFileExtensions=false /property:Configuration="Release" /property:ApplicationVersion="1.0.0.0" /property:InstallUrl="https://example.com" /property:UpdateEnabled="true" /property:UpdateMode="Foreground" /property:UpdateInterval="0" /property:UpdateIntervalUnits="days" /property:PublisherName="Example" /property:ProductName="Example Outlook Add-In" /property:FriendlyName="Example Outlook Add-In" /property:LoadBehavior="3" /property:BootstrapperEnabled="true" /property:IsWebBootstrapper="true"

:: Sign the exe
signtool sign /fd SHA1 /f "certificate.pfx" "publish\setup.exe"

:: Sign the application manifest
mage -sign "publish\Application Files\Example_1_0_0_0\Example.dll.manifest" -CertFile "certificate.pfx"
mage -update "publish\Application Files\Example_1_0_0_0\Example.dll.manifest" -CertFile "certificate.pfx" -algorithm sha1RSA

:: Sign the deployment manifests (there are 2 locations)
mage -update "publish\Application Files\Example_1_0_0_0\Example.vsto" -appmanifest "publish\Application Files\Example_1_0_0_0\Example.dll.manifest" -CertFile "certificate.pfx" -algorithm sha1RSA
mage -update "publish\Example.vsto" -appmanifest "publish\Application Files\Example_1_0_0_0\Example.dll.manifest" -CertFile "certificate.pfx" -algorithm sha1RSA
```

I have tried many tweaks to this script and this is where i've gotten. Everything works just fine if I publish with the same certificate.pfx using the Visual Studio "Publish Now" button, but I would like to get it working on command line for automation.

Comment: Hmm, good question. Perhaps you could resort to running `procexp` to see exactly what tools VS is calling (and their arguments)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As user2404450 correctly wrote, the problem cannot be solved with Mage included in any VS 2013 Update. Microsoft has updated the API, but not the mage.exe tool. If you add the "-algorithm sha1RSA" parameter while calling mage.exe, you only specify what digest algorithm to use when generating hashes for your application resources.

To solve this, we have written a small tool that calls the correct API, see an example:

```
Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.SecurityUtilities.SignFile(certThumbprint, timestampUrl, path, "v4.0");
```

You have to install VS 2013 Update 3 to get the 4th parameter working.

Comment: The mentioned SignFile(...) method is in Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808242/where-is-microsoft-build-tasks-core-dll-located)

Comment: This response is old.  Do we know if a newer version of mage supports the new API?

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out how to do it with just msbuild

I have Visual Studio 2013 with Update 3 installed. Loaded the certificates needed into the store using the project **Properties > Signing** tab, taking note of the **<ManifestCertificateThumbprint>** in the .csproj file for each certificate. Then you can use them on command line like this:

```
msbuild /target:publish /property:ManifestKeyFile="certificate.pfx" /property:ManifestCertificateThumbprint="CERTIFICATE THUMBPRINT"
```

Comment: Ok, but you didn't actually answer your original question. I need to do what you're doing in the question because I'm munging the manifest via code first and need to re-sign apart from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot accompish this using mage. The reason is that mage is not updated to use the new API added in VS2013 Update 3.

However, it turns out the new [API in VS2013 Update 3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771584(v=vs.121).aspx) are public so you can simply create a simple console app that uses this API to sign your code. Simply pass "3.5" or "4.0" as the last parameter (targetFrameworkVersion) and you're set. Also note that this method requires your certificate to be present in a certificate store.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding this to the .csproj/.vbproj file

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">   
    <!-- ... at the end of the file ... -->
    <PropertyGroup>
        <CertHash>YOUR HASH CERT THUMBPRINT</CertHash>
        <TimeStampUri>YOUR TIME SERVER</TimeStampUri>
        <SHA>SHA256</SHA>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="AfterCompile" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' or '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
        <Exec Command="signtool.exe sign /sha1 $(CertHash) /fd $(SHA) /td $(SHA) /tr $(TimeStampUri) /v &quot;$(ProjectDir)obj\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetFileName)&quot;" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="SignManifest" AfterTargets="_DeploymentSignClickOnceDeployment" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' or '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
        <Exec Command="signtool.exe sign /sha1 $(CertHash) /fd $(SHA) /td $(SHA) /tr $(TimeStampUri) /v &quot;$(PublishDir)\setup.exe&quot;" />
        <Exec Command="mage.exe -Sign &quot;$(_DeploymentApplicationDir)$(_DeploymentTargetApplicationManifestFileName)&quot; -Algorithm $(SHA)RSA -CertHash $(CertHash) -TimeStampUri $(TimeStampUri)" />
        <Exec Command="mage.exe -Update &quot;$(PublishDir)$(TargetDeployManifestFileName)&quot; -Algorithm $(SHA)RSA -CertHash $(CertHash) -TimeStampUri $(TimeStampUri) -AppManifest &quot;$(_DeploymentApplicationDir)$(_DeploymentTargetApplicationManifestFileName)&quot;" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```