# Where is Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll located?

Tags: .net, dll

I'm trying to sign a ClickOnce application using a method overload that was specifically added in VS 2013 Update 3. ([per this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29209445/734914))

The class he is using is described by [MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771584(v=vs.121).aspx), and it says the class comes from Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll. Notice that the usual "Other Versions" dropdown is missing, because this is only in Visual Studio 2013.

**Where is Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll?**

Since it says MSBuild is now deployed separately from .NET Framework, I tried looking here but no luck: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0

Comment: The documentation is incorrect, somewhat inevitable with MSBuild being rather a version mess.  It is actually Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll

Comment: awesome, copy/paste your comment into an answer so i can mark it as Accepted.

Comment: I don't want to maintain such an answer, it is a moving target.  You can post it yourself, it is much easier for you to delete it again when it gets outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Visual Studio 2013**

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll

**Visual Studio 2015**

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, in VS2015 the dll is named Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll and can be found at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin"

Comment: thanks! updated my answer above to include this info